# Does react native support loading image according to dpi

Tags: react-native, dpi

Something like drawable-xdpi drawabale-xxdpi in Android and @2x @3x in iOS?

Here is the sample

```
 <Image
   source={require('./img/3.jpg')}
   resizeMode='cover'/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add different sizes of images in a folder. It is similar to ios implementation.

```
└── img
   ├── check@2x.png
   └── check@3x.png
```

usage

```
<Image source={require('./img/check.png')} />
```

Packager will bundle and serve the image corresponding to the device's screen density, e.g.

You had better read this page for better understanding.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Comment: it works, thanks a lot. by reading  the page, there is another way to do that by using uri points to xxx in drawable folder in Android and xxx in assets in iOS.  for example, <Image  source={{uri: 'voice-run'}}/> where voice-run.png locates in drawable-xdpi, drawable-xxdpi and voice-run@2x.png voice-run@3x.png locates in images.xcassets in iOS

Comment: Its not working for me if I add '@2x' & '@3x' images inside src/images folder path , the bundles is not able to bundle it . Not sure if there is any issue on my side or others are also facing the same problem.